# Retrieving *number* pages by page id

Tags: php, wordpress

**Hello all**,

**Resolved**

I am currently trying to develop a plugin for wordpress to output three pages into one page, the reason for this is to create something like below.

[image: How i would want the plugin to output the information]

I have looked around and not seen something similar to what i am wanting to do.

Below is my code & output. **EDITED BELOW CODE: as according to Pieter Goosen**

```
<?php
function page_list( $atts ) {

        //extracting input parameters (attributes of shortcode)
        shortcode_atts( array(
            'pages' => ''
        ), $atts );

/***************************************************Out***********************************************************/

$i = '';

// Get the page id by the page name

$page_names = explode(",", $atts['pages']);

foreach($page_names as $page_name) {


    $page = get_page_by_title( ''.$page_name.'', OBJECT, 'page' );

        //argument it

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'page_id' => ''.$page->ID.''
        );

        // The Query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // The Loop
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

            $i .= '<div class="page-information">';

            $i .= '<div class="page-information-color">';

            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

                $the_query->the_post();

                $i .= '<div class="page-information-widget" style="padding-left: 20px;">';

                $i .= '<div><a href="'.get_permalink( $the_query->ID).'"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-81" src="'.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($the_query->ID,'thumbnail') ).'" alt="" width="auto" height="70" /></a></div>';

                $i .= '<div><h4>'.get_the_title().'</h4></div>';

                $i .= '<div> '.wp_trim_words( get_the_excerpt(), 19, '...').' </div>';

                $i .= '<div><a href="'.get_permalink( $the_query->ID).'"><button class="news-widget-button" type="button">More info &#x3e;</button></a></div>';

                $i .= '</div>';


            }

            $i .= '</div>';

            $i .= '</div>';

        } else {

            echo 'No Pages Found! :(';

        }

        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();

}

//returning the output to page
return $i;
}
//instantiate the shortcode
add_shortcode( 'list_pages', 'page_list' );

?>
```

[image]

This continues further down the page another 5/6 times.

**I wondering why**:

1. **I have multiple entry's**
2. **They're not the pages I requested**

Could anybody possibly help, fix the probelms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved**

What I done:

1. Removed the second foreach ( creating twice as many duplicates)
2. Adjusted the global output ( Changed it to a less guessable output )
3. Changed the posts_per_page ( As its in a foreach it would get looped, there is no need for three, 1 will do. user can then specify how many pages to display.)
4. Adjusted the placement of the main container divs classed "page-information && page-information-color"

Please feel free to manipulate below in your own answer for more efficiency or for different adaptions.

```
<?php
function page_list( $atts ) {

    //extracting input parameters (attributes of shortcode)
    shortcode_atts( array(
                'pages' => ''
            ), $atts );

    /***************************************************Out***********************************************************/

    $i = '';

    // Get the page id by the page name

    $page_names = explode(",", $atts['pages']);

    $i .= '<div class="page-information">';

    $i .= '<div class="page-information-color">';

    foreach($page_names as $page_name) {


        $page = get_page_by_title( ''.$page_name.'', OBJECT, 'page' );

        //argument it

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'page_id' => ''.$page->ID.''
        );

        // The Query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // The Loop
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

                $the_query->the_post();

                $i .= '<div class="page-information-widget" style="padding-left: 20px;">';

                $i .= '<div><a href="'.get_permalink( $the_query->ID).'"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-81" src="'.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($the_query->ID,'thumbnail') ).'" alt="" width="auto" height="70" /></a></div>';

                $i .= '<div><h4>'.get_the_title().'</h4></div>';

                $i .= '<div> '.wp_trim_words( get_the_excerpt(), 19, '...').' </div>';

                $i .= '<div><a href="'.get_permalink( $the_query->ID).'"><button class="news-widget-button" type="button">More info &#x3e;</button></a></div>';

                $i .= '</div>';


            }

        } else {

            echo 'No Pages Found! :(';

        }

        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();

    }

    $i .= '</div>';

    $i .= '</div>';

    //returning the output to page
    return $i;
    }
     //instantiate the shortcode
    add_shortcode( 'list_pages', 'page_list' );

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
'page__in' => ''.$page->ID.''
```

- `page__in` does not exists in [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)
- Whatever `''.$page->ID.''` is, no one knows. This is for you to explain how you got to this

The above line should be

```
 'page_id' => $page_id->ID,
```

### EDIT

Your code is very sloppy and error prone, sorry to say

- Never ever use `extract()`. It has been removed for very specific reasons from core almost two years ago. Please see the Shortcode API on how to properly use attributes without `extract()`
- `global $out` is really poor coding. Creating globals is evil and should be avoided. Giving your globals easy variable names like `$out` is even a bigger evil and sin. Just remember, if you use `$out` outside context, you break your global
- Your variable names are confusing, `$page` vs `$Page`. You should avoid this. This in a year's time will look like a spelling mistake, and you know what that leads to. This can be really crappy and frustrating to debug due to the similarity in variable names

Comment: I managed to get the code when back dating and not cleaning it up correctly that's why `$page->ID ` appears out of no where.

Comment: I do now have two of my three pages requested, still outputting the default first three original alongside.

Comment: How are you using your shortcode and how are you passing your pages to the shortcode

Comment: Just one note, I did not had a proper look at what is **inside** your loop, but you are getting stuff inside your loop with `$the_query->ID` as post id. This is wrong, it should be `$post->ID` or `get_the_ID()`